# displaying website in popup with javascript on element hover

Tags: javascript, html, popup

I am trying to have a dynamic popup window in an html page. the popup will appear when the user hovers a word. and in the popup window i want to call a webpage with the hovered word as parameter. It does not need to work on every word in the page. Only hover on the words i select will work like that. 
For example i have a text "hello this is a sample text"  in my html page and the user hovers the mouse on the word "sample" a popup will appear and in the popup i will show the following page "www.blabla.com/?word=sample"

hope i was clear. 
I want it to be able to work on a static page. I am very new to javascript. I am not even sure where to start so any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

edit: i want the popup to be a modal popup.

Comment: First learn HTML and Javascript and how events work in the DOM. I'll give you a hint: You can use an `iframe` inside the popup.

Comment: i'm prety sure the popup window won't open on mouse hover due to the browser blocking it. You would have to make the user click the word for it to work. An alternative would be to create a "pseudo popup" (div position absolute) with an iframe in it like @Robusto hinted

Answer (score 0):

That is very basic, read tutorials on http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascriptevents.php and http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp

But I can tell you, that with this sort of method, browsers will trigger their pop up blocker.

Answer (score 0):

Get the elements you want to have this effect, loop over them, add event listeners to each of them which pops a window up.

This is a crude implementation of something like this, where the words have the class `popup` around them:

```
[].slice.apply(document.getElementsByClassName('popup')).forEach(function (elem){
    elem.addEventListener('mouseover', function (){
        window.open('http://google.com/?q=' + this.innerHTML);
    }, false);
});​
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/amaan/pgDPM/)